# Php contact form having issue sending email

Tags: php, html

I setup a contact form and for some reason it does not want to send email. I did the mailtester.php and that sent the email so my host is setup correctly. Not sure what the issue is.

contact.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  </head>
  <body>
 <?php  include('template/header.php'); ?>
      <div class="container">
    <form class="well form-horizontal" action="send_form_email.php " method="post" name="contactform" id="contact_form">
<fieldset>
<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Contact Us with Suggestions or Feedbacks</legend>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Last Name</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
  <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone #</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
  <input name="telephone" placeholder="(845)555-1212" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Text area -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Suggestion</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Success message -->
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up">
  </i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>
<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
      </div><!--/row-->
      <hr>
   <?php  include('template/footer.php'); ?>
    </div><!--/.container-->
                <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

send_form_email.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "admin@greenwoodatnashuanh.org";

    $email_subject = "Feedback or Inquiry";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



<h3>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.<h3>
<p>Page will be redirect back to contact form 5 sec</p>

 <?php 
 header( "refresh:5;url=http://sample.org/contact.php" );

die();?>

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: My advice: put static values instead of variables in mail function. This way you will see wich variable is wrong.